# Malloc'ing a double pointer structure inside a struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

C noob here. I'm trying to initialize a simple struct as follows:

```
typedef struct person_s {
    char *fname;                 ///< first name of the person
    char *lname;                 ///< last name of the person
    char *handle;               ///< handle of the person
    struct person_s **friends;  ///< dynamic collection of friends
    size_t friend_count;        ///< current number of friends
    size_t max_friends;         ///< current limit on friends
} person_t;
```

I think I understand using malloc for every single member in this struct, except for the double pointer friends struct in it. How do I allocate memory for this double pointer?

Here's my malloc for the other data members:

```
person_t *newperson(char *fn, char *ln, char *han){
    person_t *p = NULL;
    p = malloc(sizeof(person_t));

    p->fname = malloc(strlen(fn) +1);
    strcpy(p->fname, fn);

    p->lname = malloc(strlen(ln) +1);
    strcpy(p->lname, ln);

    p->handle = malloc(strlen(han) +1);
    strcpy(p->handle, han);

    p->*friends = malloc(sizeof(*friends));

    p->friend_count = malloc(2*sizeof(friend_count));
    p->friend_count = 0;

    p->max_friends = malloc(2*sizeof(max_friends));
    p->friend_count = 0;
}
```

Edit: my bad, I forgot to include that this is inside a function that initializes this struct.

Edit1: In response to the comments, what I'm trying to achieve here is to make a dynamic "array" of friends that is pointed by the p->friends data member. Additionally, I have a dynamic hash table, would it be a good idea to use it as a collection for putting all the friends linked to this person? The concept of pointers and dynamic allocation is still somewhat confusing to me so sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: you expect at most `max_friends` friends. Hence you need to allocate space for `max_friend` pointers to other friends. `p->friends = malloc(max_friends * sizeof(*person_s))`

Comment: Why do you think you need a double pointer here for `friends`?

Comment: *"How do I allocate memory for this double pointer?"* - The question is not how. The question is why. This is an XY-problem.

Comment: This is why `stackoverflow` is going down the drain: close-happy people. Why don't y'all just answer the question, or let someone else answer it, instead of closing it based on the entirely unwarranted assumption that you know better than the OP what it is that the OP is trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oh, sorry if I'm wrong but I was under the impression that a dynamic collection of structs would require double pointers? So a pointer to a pointer of an array of structures for friends?

Comment: @AK Not true. It's no different from "a collection of characters", like `fname`

Comment: @AK well, it all depends what you want to do. The answer below addresses this issue

Comment: Also, there's no reason to have different name for `person_s` and `person_t`

Comment: Another thing, remember to minimize your code before posting. You have a lot of different fields that only bloats your question. And the fact that the ptp is inside a struct makes no difference.

Comment: @klutt gotcha, will do thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single pointer is enough for dynamic collection:

```
struct person_s *friends;
```

...

```
p->friends = malloc(max_friends * sizeof(struct person_s));
```

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, thanks! I thought a collection would require double pointers because I'm trying to make an "array" of a struct of friends (of the same type) that are linked to a person through this friend data member.

Comment: Or much better: `p->friends = malloc(max_friends * sizeof(*(p->friends));`

Comment: Better still: `p->friends = malloc(sizeof *p->friends * max_friends);` (it's a good habit to put the `size_t` value first, which can avoid an overflow in the case of `int * int  * size_t`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep the syntax simple, let us assume you have `typedef`ed `struct person_s` as `person`.

A pointer to pointer is the same thing as a pointer to an array of pointers.

So, first you need to allocate the array, then you need to allocate individual elements within the array.

This will allocate the array:

```
friends = malloc(max_friends * sizeof(*friends));
```

This works, because `friends` is of type `**person`, so `*friends` must be of type `*person`.

Then, you will need a `for` loop in which you allocate each `person`:

```
friends[i] = malloc(sizeof(**friends)); //or sizeof(person), same thing.
```

(I typed the above immediately after the question was posted, only to find out that the question was closed before I had the chance to answer. Then later the question was opened, but I was never notified. I am posting it because I would hate to just throw it away now.)